# command to keep only the name of a file

Tags: bash

is there any command in linux to keep only the name of a file without its extension
I am creating a backup of txt files, when I generate the files with a script the extension is .txt.bkp and I only want the extension .bkp

```
file=$1
cat $file > $file.fasta
```

Answer (score 2):

This bash expansion will do it: `${file%.*}`.

Comment: thank you I have already solved my doubt but thank you very much.